# What would be type of reference (or pointer) when const is used with auto?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
const int i = 42;
const auto &k = i;
```

`k` should be `const int&` or just `int` (because `const` is already specified before `auto`) ?

Note:
`cout << "k  is " << typeid(k).name() << endl;` prints `i`

Comment: `k` would be of type `const int&`, referring to `i`. [Easy to verify](http://rextester.com/XCXP29391) by comparing `&i` and `&k`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, then why is typeid(k).name() showing it as just i and how the extra const (before auto) behave in this case ? , Thanks for your help !

Comment: `const` does nothing - the outcome would be the same without it. With `const`, `auto` is deduced as `int` and `k` is then `const int&`. Without `const`, `auto` would be deduced as `const int` and `k` would still be `const int&`. `typeid` obtains the type of the expression - expression `k` is an lvalue of type `int` (there ain't no such thing as an expression having reference type).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik [Can't say I agree with you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65ccaa89a819715a)

Comment: "With const, auto is deduced as int and k is then const int&" -- your this statement makes it clear why  typeid(k).name() is i.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: Well, the output of your test code agrees with him.

Comment: @OnkarNMahajan it seems your real question is about `typeid` ...

Answer (score 1):

I continued your code like this

```
const int i = 42;
const auto &k = i;

k = 21;
```

and get the error message:

```
error: cannot assign to variable 'k' with const-qualified type 'const int &'
```

So k is clearly of type 'const int &'. Obviously typeid is not able to capture the hole type. But of course the compiler is.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure if two types are the same, you can always check using [std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    const int i = 42;
    const auto &k = i;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<decltype(i), std::remove_reference<decltype(k)>::type>::value << std::endl;
}
```